# Why is porcupine quill used in seemantham samskara?

Tags: rituals, samskara

In the Seemantham (baby shower) samskara, a porcupine quill is used to draw a line straight from navel of expectant mother to her forehead - thrice, amid constant prayers and chants.

As per this [blog](http://anuharish96.blogspot.com/2017/11/Seemantham-Pumsuvanam-Iyer-Baby-Shower.html) post,

> Porcupine is one animal which cannot be easily killed, thanks to it's prickly exterior coat. The father prays for the well-being of his unborn child and **hopes the god's will protect his baby as the porcupine is protected by the sharp quills.**

> One of my acquaintances on Facebook, Ruckmani Ananthanarayanan says, "Regarding porcupine quill , I wish to share what our vaadhyaar said during my seemantham, 5 years ago. He asked to draw a line with it from my navel to the center of my head. The **naadi connecting to the cervix is supposed to be there** it seems. He said a gentle prick has to be given so that it initiates the opening of the cervix gradually, enabling **normal delivery**...

Question is whether the above has basis in scriptures or relevant text ? Or is there another reason for porcupine quill being used ?